# Issues with dropdown select_tag placeholder with prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I'm having an issue with setting a placeholder within dropdown selection form using the rails select_tag helper. Using the prompt option a placeholder exists, but this method produces a dead duplicate value in the dropdown that you can't click:

[image: duplicate_dropdown]

Here is my code:

```
@posts = Post.all
@categories = Post.uniq.pluck(:category)
@prompt = "Select Category"

if params[:category]
   @posts = Post.where(category: params[:category])
   @prompt = params[:category]
end

<%= form_tag(h_path, :method => "get") do %>
   <%= select_tag 'category', options_for_select(@categories), {onchange: "this.form.submit();", prompt: @prompt} %>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas or suggestions regarding making a placeholder value work nicely in this context would be greatly appreciated. By nicely I mean something like the category dropdown select example on this page:
http://www.joeabercrombie.com/category/audiobooks/

Answer (score 1):

What you need is not a prompt. Prompt is a message to user to show what this dropdown means. From your Audible's page example, in the category select dropdown "Select Category" is the prompt.

What you need is to set a selected option. You want to select an option from the existing select options if `params[:category]` is set. In that case, rename your variables and pass the "to be selected" option to `options_for_select` of `select_tag` helper.

```
@posts = Post.all
@categories = Post.uniq.pluck(:category)
@prompt = "Select Category"

if params[:category]
   @posts = Post.where(category: params[:category])
   @selected_category = params[:category]
end

<%= form_tag(h_path, :method => "get") do %>
   <%= select_tag 'category', options_for_select(@categories, @selected_category), {onchange: "this.form.submit();", prompt: @prompt} %>
<% end %>
```

Reference: [select_tag (ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper) - APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass `params[:category]` as already selected value to `select_tag`

And also move `uniq` to the end `line:2`

```
@posts = Post.all
@categories = Post.pluck(:category).uniq

if params[:category]
  @posts = Post.where(category: params[:category])
end

<%= form_tag(h_path, method: :get) do %>
   <%= select_tag :category, options_for_select(@categories, params[:category]), onchange: "this.form.submit();", prompt: "Select Category" %>
<% end %>
```